# How to know difference between [ENTER] and [SPACE] in bash

Tags: bash, special-characters

I want to make a script that functions differently when pressed [Space] and differently when pressed [Enter] .

what i tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -n1 Input

if [[ $Input == \n ]]; then
    echo "Enter is Pressed"
elif [[ $Input == "" ]]; then
    echo "Space is pressed"
fi
```

Any suggestions or advice is very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
#! /bin/bash

read -r -N1 Input

case $Input in
    $'\n')  echo "Enter is Pressed";;
    ' ')    echo "Space is pressed";;
esac
```

- The `-r` option for `read` prevents special handling of backslash (`\`) characters.
- The `-N` (instead of `-n`) option for `read` prevents special handling of delimiter characters (including space and newline).
- `$'\n'` is Bash [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting).
- I used `case` instead of `if` just because it's a bit less verbose in this example.

Answer (score 0):

```
read -N 1 input
echo 
if [[ "$input" == $'\x0a' ]]; then
   echo "Enter is Pressed" 
elif [[ "$input" == $'\x20' ]]; then
   echo "Space is Pressed" 
else
   echo "'$input' is Pressed" 
fi
```